# How to hide path location in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, path, drupal-7

How to hide path file in drupal now it looks like this:

```
 http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/document.pdf
```

I what to change to look something like this:

```
 http://localhost/drupal/media/view.php?id=6445
```

Comment: I think you should use http://drupal.stackexchange.com for Drupal related questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this module to achieve that requirement.

https://www.drupal.org/project/file_aliases